# Idiomatic way to call external APIs from Salesforce

Tags: asynchronous, streaming-api, post

I'm new to Salesforce, and am looking for advice on how to best approach a scenario where a Salesforce runtime communicates with an external REST-service that is under my control. My background is web-development, so I assumed to just run a POST-request from Salesforce and wait for the response. My colleagues told me that that's not the "Salesforce-way" because it would be a synchronous workload, and proposed to modify the service such that it writes its response into the Salesforce-db instead.

I dislike that approach, but am having difficulties sifting through the docpages in order to come up with an alternative. What I was hoping to find was a way to define an external resource, when to call it, and where to write its response, without writing the code to make it async and let Salesforce handle that.

Comment: I recommend you spend a bit of time with [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com), including [Apex REST Callouts](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_rest_callouts) and [Use External Services With a Flow](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/use-external-services-with-a-flow) amongst others. You also have the opportunity to leverage middlware, such as MuleSoft. Anyway, best if you get informed using the available resources and if you still have specific questions come back to SFSE and ask.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update the question with my results.